# AngularJS $interval or $timeout

Tags: angularjs

I've built a small search app (movies) using AngularJS and Elasticsearch. In testing it out, I realized I forgot to add a timeout for when things take longer than planned, but I'm having trouble getting it to work. I actually decided to use $interval instead of $timeout because it seems better in terms of it still working to get results instead of just stopping the process when it takes longer.

Here is my code:

```
    vm.search = function() {
    vm.currentPage = 1;
    vm.results.documents = [];
    vm.isSearching = true;
    $state.go('search');
    return searchService.search(vm.searchTerms, vm.currentPage).then(function(es_return) {      
      var totalItems = es_return.hits.total;
      var totalTime = es_return.took;
      var numPages = Math.ceil(es_return.hits.total / vm.itemsPerPage);
      vm.results.pagination = [];
      for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        vm.results.totalItems = totalItems;
        vm.results.queryTime = totalTime;

        vm.results.pagination = searchService.formatResults(es_return.hits.hits);//load all results
        vm.results.documents = vm.results.pagination.slice(vm.currentPage, vm.itemsPerPage);
        } 
          vm.noResults = true;
        }
    ),
    function(error){
      console.log('ERROR: ', error.message);
      vm.isSearching = false;
    }
  };
```

And I'm trying to figure out where to put

```
if(totalItems > 0) {
  $interval(function(){
    vm.isSearching = true;
  }, 2000);
```

in there.

I've tried putting it in the for loop but no joy :(

Comment: Explain the expected behavior you are looking for

Comment: @charlietfl - basically just looking for some way to indicate to the user that the search results are taking longer than expected to return - to be able to give them a "loading" message - something to that effect

Comment: where are you returning `vm.search` to? You are doing a redirect before the return. That seems very suspicious. Using an interval timer doesn't make sense either... you only need to turn it on once and turn it off when request completes or fails

Comment: @charlietfl - it returns to the results page. I figured $interval instead of $timeout so that it eventually returns something instead of nothing... for instance having an $interval of 3 seconds instead of a $timeout of 3 seconds. I'm just looking to indicate to the user that results are on the way.

Comment: Sounds structurally wrong ... but I don't know where this `vm.search` is. If it's in a controller outside of your `<ui-view>`  I guess it makes sense otherwise it doesn't. Really not enough known scope wise here

Comment: @charlietfl, yes this is in my controller.

Comment: @charlietfl, I've been looking into this all day, lots searching and reading. I think I have a better concept of how to do this now. Forget the $timeout and $interval stuff. It seems using resolves in my $state config with UI Router is the best practice way to go about this, would you agree?

Answer (score 0):

You could chain the promise further and generate a defer from `$q` (TypeScript: $q:IQService) and reject it after a certain amount of time and show the rejection message.

`var defer = $q.defer();`

and somewhere return `defer.promise`

```
SearchService.$inject = ["$q", "$http"]
function SearchService($q, $http) {
    var defaultWaitUntilTimeout = 2000;
    this.search = function (param, param2, waitUntilTimeout) {
        var defer = $q.defer();

        $http().get().then(function (result) { defer.resolve(result);})

        $timeout(function () { defer.reject();}, waitUntilTimeout || defaultWaitUntilTimeout); // now the rejection function of the promise will get called

        return defer.promise;
    }
}
```

I hope you get the idea

Comment: this is a convoluted way to go about it compared to using `timeout` in config of `$http` and simply return `$http`